# [Un]expected Cassandra "lightweight transaction" behavior

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

Here is the problem that needs reasoning/explanation about lightweight transactions in Cassandra using Java driver from DataStax.

I wanted an insert operation which succeeds only if data does not exist already. To achieve this CQL's `IF` clause is used. Here is the code:

```
public boolean insert( String key, String value )
{
    String cql = QueryBuilder.insertInto( KEYSPACE, TABLE_NAME )
            .ifNotExists()
            .value( COL_1, QueryBuilder.bindMarker() )
            .value( COL_2, QueryBuilder.bindMarker() )
            .toString();

    Row row = session.execute( cql, key, value ).one();
    return row.getBool( 0 ); // this is equivalent to row.getBool("applied")
}

public void delete( String key )
{
    String cql = QueryBuilder.delete().from( KEYSPACE, TABLE_NAME )
            .where( QueryBuilder.eq( COL_1, QueryBuilder.bindMarker() ) )
            .toString();
    session.execute( cql, key );
}
```

[In `insert` method code, `applied` column is used to check the result of conditional queries](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/jd-faq.html#faq-conditional-statement)

Let me note that `COL_1` is a primary key here, and the code is a simplified version taken from working environment. Now one would expect the following behavior for repeated calls of this triple:

```
delete("key");
insert("key", "value"); // returns true
insert("key", "value"); // returns false
```

Yes, that's the expected result and it is exactly what happens. **But not always!** Our unit tests were failing sometimes for some unknown reasons - second insert was returning true. I was crazy about this, and finally found the solution -- adding an `IF` clause to delete operation removed all unexpected results on repeated calls.

Now I am interested what would be the reason behind all that. Why does CAS(compare and set) technique used in `insert` by using `IF` clause not sufficient? Why there should be `IF` clause in `delete` operation?

Comment: What consistency level for insert/delete queries did you use?

Comment: @shuty I imagine one based on `.one();` statement.

Comment: @shutty I don't specify consistency level explicitly, so it should be the default one - ONE

Comment: @Bazi what does the delete with `IF` clause look like?

Comment: @MinhPham i used `ifExists()` of `QueryBuilder` when building the delete query.